# nodejs making outbound HTTP requests as quickly as possible

Tags: node.js, http, networking, request

I have a situation where I am receiving an event and need to respond by pumping out huge numbers of outbound HTTP requests. With the code that I have now, I'm hitting roughly 500rps. Before scaling horizontally, I'd like to push things to the max vertically. It's unclear to me exactly *what* is limiting my maximum requests per second.

I'm using keepaliveagent and request-promise-native for making my requests. Something along the lines of this:

```
const keepaliveAgent = new HttpsAgent({
    maxSockets: 256,
    maxFreeSockets: 100,
    timeout: 60000, // active socket keepalive for 60 seconds
    freeSocketTimeout: 30000, // free socket keepalive for 30 seconds
});

const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: `${my_url}`,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.kafka.json.v1+json',
    },
    body: {
        key: keyValue,
        value: message,
    },
    json: true,
    resolveWithFullResponse: true,
    agent: keepaliveAgent,
};

const arrayOfThings = [1,2,3,4,5...10000];
const promises = arrayOfThings.map(async thing => {
    const response = await requestPromise(options);
});
await Promise.all(promises);
```

Is there anything that I can do to increase my current outbound requests per second?

Comment: not an answer per se, but you could be hitting limits not just from node but from the underlying OS as well.  Depending on your OS, you should look at the network tuning parameters around concurrent connections, buffer sizes, NAT table sizes, etc.  All may be part of this equation.

Comment: What about not trying to await on the requestPromise  this might make your loop iterate faster.

Comment: Alec, did you make any progress on this? curious on the same problem as well. @damitj07 that would just end the program before the request gets a response.